# Karate - How to use retry until when there are 2 different requests in the same scenario

Tags: karate

If I send one request in a scenario and use retry until as shown in the syntax below then the retry until works fine:

```
  Scenario Outline: x
    Given url 'x'
    Then retry until status 200
    When method get
    
    Examples:
      | productId | postcode | 
      | 'xxxx' | 'yyyy' |
```

However, if I then send ANY other request afterwards (to make things simple I will just send exactly the same request)..

```
  Scenario Outline: x
    Given url 'x'
    Then retry until status 200
    When method get

    //Send ANY other request here:
    When method get
    
    Examples:
      | productId | postcode | 
      | 'xxxx' | 'yyyy' |
```

Then I see the following error message:

```
11:59:09.820 [main] WARN  com.intuit.karate - retry condition evaluation failed: js failed:
>>>>
01: status 200
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:7 Expected ; but found 200
status 200
       ^
```

How do I use retry until when there is more than one request sent in the scenario?

Answer (score 1):

(1) retry until must come BEFORE each method keyword
(2) The correct syntax = retry until responseStatus == 200

```
Scenario Outline: x
    Given url 'x'
    Then retry until responseStatus == 200
    When method get

    //Send ANY other request here:
    Then retry until responseStatus == 200
    When method get
    
    Examples:
      | productId | postcode | 
      | 'xxxx' | 'yyyy' |
```

Answer (score 0):

The `retry` should always be *before* the `method` keyword. Read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#retry-until

Comment: Thanks Peter. I have moved the retry before the first method. However, the problem still remains. If I add a 2nd 'method' i.e. I send a 2nd request I see 'SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:7 Expected ; but found 200. Is it not possible to send 2 requests in the same Scenario when you have used retry until?

Comment: @Matt sorry, I pass on this one. time for you to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Sorry Peter I have figured out what I was doing wrong now. I was using 'Then retry until status 200' when I should have been using 'Then retry until responseStatus == 200'

Answer (score 0):

This is the perefect example to use retry:

```
* url demoBaseUrl
* path 'greeting'
* retry until responseStatus == 200
* method GET
```

Note: When method GET should be used only after the retry line